# How to scan a list of computers and find the last logged in user and the date this user logged in

Tags: powershell

I have the following script from a previous stackoverflow question.It works in that the script successfully scans my list of computers to report back my userid logged in for each computer.

But what I'm looking for is the last logged in user for each computer in my list.  I don't want to scan Active Directory as I don't have access to do that. Here is the code I found that is getting me partway there:

```
    Get-Content -Path c:\ListOfMachines.txt | % {
  Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_ -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -erroraction silentlycontinue | % {
    "$($_.Name): $($_.username)"
  }
}
```

Like I said it works in that it scans each computer in my list but I want it to report back the last logged in user and the date they logged in.  Is this something someone has seen before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can grab the user [SID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778824%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) with the most recent LastUseTime in the [Win32_UserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class and assign it to a $User variable:

```
$last_user= Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $_ -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Sort-Object -Property LastUseTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
$UserSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($last_user.sid) 
$User = $UserSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
```

To format the date from the $last_user:

```
[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($last_user.LastUseTime)
```